# How to show that a category with products and equalizers of at most size $k$ has all limits of at most size $k$?

Tags: category-theory

I am reading a nice book called category theory by S. Awodey and on page 104 he proves the above statement, which unfortunately for me is a bit sterile. I was wishing to see a picture-like construction of limit out of products and equalizers, preferably demonstrated for a little drawable diagram. I would be very thankful if some one could help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: What does products and equalizers of size $k$ precisely mean?

Comment: If k is an (infinte) cardinal, limits of size k are limits of diagrams whose index category has at most k morphisms (or objects).

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in detail in the book by Mac Lane, Categories for the working mathematician, Theorem V.2.1.